# Who pays the bill for Bing Maps API calls?

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I reference this [MSDN resource on Bing Maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff859477.aspx) on Bing Maps API usage reports.
As developers we usually register for Bing Maps key and embed it within wp7 apps when using Bing Maps controls. I happen to use this API WS: `ReverseGeocode`, which is billable API.
Will I pay the bill as developer?

Comment: Ask Microsoft Billing / The Bing Maps Team, rather than random strangers on the internet. But you would have to have registered a valid payment method for it to be billable, so if you haven't then...

Comment: Have you seen the * mentioning "*This category is not billable if it occurs within the context of an AJAX Control or Silverlight Control session." If you use it within WP7 than I think it's not billable category.

Comment: @ChristiaanV yup, I saw that bit. On my Bing Maps account, my usage report is showing wp7 sessions as billable usages.

Comment: Hmmm...strange! I would suggest like Claus already mentioned to contact Microsoft. "For information or inquires about pricing, licensing or volume licensing, contact maplic@microsoft.com."

Comment: Billable usage means that if it happens on an account/ID with billing enabled I believe. For mobile-classified apps, this is not the case. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got response from Bing Maps team:

> Julius, even though our transactions are broken down into Billable and
>   Non-billable. You are not required to pay for Billable transactions if
>   you are using the API under the Terms of Use for Mobile applications.
>   Regards,  Brian Webb Bing Maps for Enterprise (formerly Virtual Earth)

http://www.microsoft.com/maps

Answer (score 4):

Please review the mobile guidelines here: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/licensing_for_mobile.aspx

It implies that it is without cost.

```
Developers can use Bing Maps in mobile applications for free, under the following conditions:

Use is restricted to consumer-facing mobile applications
Offer excludes use of traffic data
Developers using the Bing Maps platform for free in mobile applications receive:

- Full choice of Bing Maps APIs
- Aerial, road, Bird’s Eye, and Streetside™
- Access to documentation and developer articles on MSDN

Access to the developer forum for support questions
```

My answer is not authoritative - I am answering only as a developer who uses these APIs in a high-traffic Windows Phone application, not as a Microsoft employee. Please contact Bing's API team if you need an authoritative answer.

See the [Bing Maps Mobile Terms of Use](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/mobileterms.html) for full details.

Comment: I dropped Bing API team an email, waiting to hear what they say.